# How to set page layout using page_layouts.yml?

Tags: alchemy-cms

I need to set the page layout, currently, I can see that the used page layout file is `application.html.haml`

how would I let the page use another file as the layout?
I thought it would be possible by using `page_layouts.yml` by setting the `name` but it seems I still missing how to do it. What does that `name` relates to? for now, its value is `index` but where is that index file?

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I could handle this but only worked at show page as:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :determine_layout

 def determine_layout
    module_name = self.class.to_s.split("::").first
    return (module_name.eql?("Alchemy") ? "pages" : "application")
  end
```

However, I still need to apply this while editing the page at admin page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `application.html.erb` file is the template for the whole Rails application. Alchemy pages have their own templates per `page_layout` stored in the `app/views/alchemy/page_layouts` folder.

Please read the guideline on how to create a page layouts and templates

https://guides.alchemy-cms.com/pages.html#page-templates

EDIT:

You are able to set the layout used in the admin page edit preview with the `admin_page_preview_layout`  setting in the `config/alchemy/config.yml`.

https://github.com/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms/blob/main/config/alchemy/config.yml#L205

Comment: Thank you @tvdeyen , but how would I use another main template than `application.html.erb` ? which Alchemy controller shall I customize?

Comment: It seems I need to set `layout` at `PagesController` but I am not sure about the proper approach.. I need to not to use the main template `application.html.erb` for the CMS pages

Comment: kindly check EDIT above

Comment: Thank you! I wish this is configured more dynamically though.